# Angular trustAsHtml not handling anchor tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

I receive a piece of HTML from the server, e.g:

```
My clicky &lt;a my-directive ui-sref='shoppingCart({item: retainItem()})'&gt;Link? &lt;/a&gt;
```

Which i can convert to HTML through the filter below:

```
app.filter('html', ['$sce', function ($sce) { 
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };    
}])
```

However this doesn't convert the `<a>` tags into actual hyperlinks.

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/worAkuD59qahYjsSK5qW?p=preview

How can i convert the value received from the server in to HTML which also include clickable anchor tags?

Answer (score 0):

You should unescape `&lt;` and `&gt;` in your string.

Comment: there is nothing to change in your plunk. You said that escaped html goes from server. If this cannot be solved in serverside, you may use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript

Comment: i can escape these server side, but if i replace with < or > then even still the <a> won't render becuase of the ui-sref

Comment: do you want to have your anchor tag directives work?

Comment: its not just the anchor tag, its the ui-sref tag. Take a look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/worAkuD59qahYjsSK5qW?p=preview  Specifically the footerDirective. The href works, the ui-sref doesnt.

Comment: To make your directives work, you should use `$compile` to instantiate them if you place template after the application bootstrap.